# The current status of diplomatic relationship between the US and Somalia

Tags: united-states, international-relations, somalia

Somalia has been rocked by civil war for nearly three decades; added to that with the rise of [extremest group like Al-Shabaab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shabaab_(militant_group)). Diplomatic relationship between the two countries has been on and off due to lack of "real" [stable government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Government_of_Somalia). Somalia was included in the newly approved travel ban set by the Trump Administration.

What's the current diplomatic state between the two nations and does the US recognize the current Somali government?

Comment: A more interesting question is, why doesn't US recognize Somaliland

Comment: @User4012. Well, it's hard to recognize Somaliland when Somalis themselves don't recognize it. I think doing something similar to South/North Sudan could work IF they can agree on something.

Comment: never stopped anyone from recognizing Kosovo

Comment: Comparison cannot be made between the two. Somalia is entrenched with tribal warfare mixed with terrorism and famine. IF US recognized Somaliland, what about other tribes who also want recognition like the Ogaden region? It's just a very messy politics and I hate to admit it but dictatorship is what kept the tribes in check before the fall in early 90s

Answer (score 1):

According to the U.S. Department of State's [website](https://www.state.gov/r/pa/ei/bgn/2863.htm), the U.S. launched a mission to Somalia in 2015. Somalia's first ambassador to the United States was created in 2014.

This was the first time in 25 years that the U.S. had a mission in Somalia.

[CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/17/us/somalia-recognition/index.html) and the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/18/world/africa/somalia-us-recognizes-government.html) reported that the United States recognized the Somali government in 2013.

All of this appears to reflect the transition to the [Republic of Somalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Government_of_Somalia), which was [inaugurated](http://allafrica.com/stories/201208220474.html) in 2012.